# Angular Universal Deployment on Heroku

Tags: angular, heroku, angular-universal

After having start with Angular Universal on this tuto :
https://coursetro.com/posts/code/68/Make-your-Angular-App-SEO-Friendly-(Angular-4-+-Universal)

I would like to know what is the next step for deploy my app to Heroku (or other). I have search a lot but i didn't find a concrete tutorial that explain me how to do it properly. Does anyone have a good source ? 
Thank you in advance

Comment: Ive found this tutorial on youtube,hope it helps
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GgWvuBdatAM

Comment: If anyone else is interested, I have created an Angular 7 Universal Starter with easy Heroku deployment [here](https://github.com/Alex61NN5/angular-universal-heroku-starter) Just clone the project, run a `yarn install` then its ready to be deployed

Answer (score 2):

I released a full tutorial on getting an Angular Universal app going with Heroku **[here](https://medium.com/augie-gardner/deploying-an-angular-universal-app-to-heroku-eca2b7966947)**

The Universal Starter [repo](https://github.com/angular/universal-starter) was my base for the project.  I made a few tweaks including adding a `Procfile`, and making sure to add a propert `postinstall` script so that Heroku can perform some building once you push the repo.

From there, it's as simple as: 

`git init
heroku login
heroku create
git add .
git commit -m "initial commit"
git push heroku master`

My [Medium article](https://medium.com/augie-gardner/deploying-an-angular-universal-app-to-heroku-eca2b7966947) explains this in greater detail.

I've also set up a repo with the ready-made changes [here](https://github.com/stephengardner/universal-starter-heroku)

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

One thing that might help you (which I ran into) is making sure your devDependencies are installed on Heroku. For that you must run:

```
 heroku config:set NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false
```

as described here https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys